# Redirect to VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have two Visualforce page(Page1 and Page2)  and **two Apex Class.**( Class 1 and Class 2).

Using javascript am connecting VF page1 to VF page2.In VF page2 have save button when i click save button it will redirect to VF page 1.

How to solve this issues.Please see this link now am working on this scenario
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/

am also tried this but nothing happen

```
PageReference newocp = new PageReference('/apex/CustomLookupController');
newocp.setRedirect(true);
return newocp;
```

**Update :**

**Apex class 1:**

```
public with sharing class CustomLookupController {
    public CustomLookupController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

  public Site__c site {get;set;}
   public CustomLookupController() {
    site = new Site__c();
  } 
}
```

**VF Page1**

```
<apex:page extensions="CustomLookupController" id="Page"  standardController="Site__c">

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  function openLookup(baseURL, width, modified, searchParam){
    var originalbaseURL = baseURL;
    var originalwidth = width;
    var originalmodified = modified;
    var originalsearchParam = searchParam;

    var lookupType = baseURL.substr(baseURL.length-3, 3);
    if (modified == '1') baseURL = baseURL + searchParam;

    var isCustomLookup = false;

    // Following "001" is the lookup type for Account object so change this as per your standard or custom object
    if(lookupType == "001"){

      var urlArr = baseURL.split("&");
      var txtId = '';
      if(urlArr.length > 2) {
        urlArr = urlArr[1].split('=');
        txtId = urlArr[1];
      }

      // Following is the url of Custom Lookup page. You need to change that accordingly
      baseURL = "/apex/CustomAccountLookup?txt=" + txtId;

      // Following is the id of apex:form control "myForm". You need to change that accordingly
      baseURL = baseURL + "&frm=" + escapeUTF("{!$Component.myForm}");
      if (modified == '1') {
        baseURL = baseURL + "&lksearch=" + searchParam;
      }

      // Following is the ID of inputField that is the lookup to be customized as custom lookup
      if(txtId.indexOf('Account') > -1 ){
        isCustomLookup = true;
      }
    }


    if(isCustomLookup == true){
      openPopup(baseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+width+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,scrollable=yes", true);
    }
    else {
      if (modified == '1') originalbaseURL = originalbaseURL + originalsearchParam;
      openPopup(originalbaseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+originalwidth+",height=180,toolbar=no,status=yes,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
    } 
  }
</script>

<apex:sectionHeader title="Demo"  subtitle="Custom Lookup" />

  <apex:form id="myForm">  
    <apex:PageBlock id="PageBlock">    
      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Custom Lookup">
        <apex:inputField id="Account" value="{!site.Account__c}"  />
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:PageBlock>
  </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Apex class 2**

```
public with sharing class CustomAccountLookup {
 public Id accId;
  public Account account {get;set;} // new account to create
  public List<Account> results{get;set;} // search results
  public string searchString{get;set;} // search keyword

  public CustomAccountLookup() {
    account = new Account();
    // get the current search string
    searchString = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('lksrch');
    runSearch();  
  }

  // performs the keyword search
  public PageReference search() {
    runSearch();
    return null;
  }

  // prepare the query and issue the search command
  private void runSearch() {
    // TODO prepare query string for complex serarches & prevent injections
    results = performSearch(searchString);               
  } 

  // run the search and return the records found. 
  private List<Account> performSearch(string searchString) {

    String soql = 'select id, name from account';
    if(searchString != '' && searchString != null)
      soql = soql +  ' where name LIKE \'%' + searchString +'%\'';
    soql = soql + ' limit 25';
    System.debug(soql);
    return database.query(soql); 

  }

  // save the new account record
  public PageReference saveAccount() {
    insert account;
    // reset the account
    account = new Account();
    return null;
    PageReference newocp = new PageReference('/apex/CustomLookupController');
            newocp.setRedirect(true);
            return newocp;
  }

  // used by the visualforce page to send the link to the right dom element
  public string getFormTag() {
    return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('frm');
  }

  // used by the visualforce page to send the link to the right dom element for the text box
  public string getTextBox() {
    return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('txt');
  }

}
```

**VF Page 2**

```
<apex:page controller="CustomAccountLookup"
  title="Search" 
  showHeader="false" 
  sideBar="false" 
  tabStyle="Account" 
  id="pg">

  <apex:form >
  <apex:outputPanel id="page" layout="block" style="margin:5px;padding:10px;padding-top:2px;">
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name1" id="tabbedPanel">

      <!-- SEARCH TAB -->
      <apex:tab label="Search" name="tab1" id="tabOne">

        <apex:actionRegion >  
          <apex:outputPanel id="top" layout="block" style="margin:5px;padding:10px;padding-top:2px;">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Search" style="font-weight:Bold;padding-right:10px;" for="txtSearch"/>
            <apex:inputText id="txtSearch" value="{!searchString}" />
              <span style="padding-left:5px"><apex:commandButton id="btnGo" value="Go" action="{!Search}" rerender="searchResults"></apex:commandButton></span>
          </apex:outputPanel>

          <apex:outputPanel id="pnlSearchResults" style="margin:10px;height:350px;overflow-Y:auto;" layout="block">
            <apex:pageBlock id="searchResults"> 
              <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!results}" var="a" id="tblResults">
                <apex:column >
                  <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:outputPanel >Name</apex:outputPanel>
                  </apex:facet>
                   <apex:outputLink value="javascript:top.window.opener.lookupPick2('{!FormTag}','{!TextBox}_lkid','{!TextBox}','{!a.Id}','{!a.Name}',false)" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(a.Id))}">{!a.Name}</apex:outputLink>     
                </apex:column>
              </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
          </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:actionRegion>

      </apex:tab>

      <!-- NEW ACCOUNT TAB -->
      <apex:tab label="New Account" name="tab2" id="tabTwo">

        <apex:pageBlock id="newAccount" title="New Account" >

          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!saveAccount}" value="Save"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
          <apex:pageMessages />

          <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.CustomAccountLookup}" var="f">
              <apex:inputField value="{!Account[f]}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
          </apex:pageBlockSection> 
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
  </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you post up your code please to help us out in debugging it?

Comment: Agree with @pbattisson, you need to post your code for us to help you. Is your Save method a pagereference method? and you have the above code in it, then you  should take you to CustomLookupController Vf page.

Comment: Are you trying to open an popup ?

Comment: What is not working here in the updated code? I had tried using Jeff's code before and i think it worked fine. Though it was a long time back

Comment: when i click save button on VF page 2 it will go to VF page 1 but it remain same page (VF page2)

Comment: Not sure if i understood this.. You open up VF page2 in a popup and when you save it page1 is loaded in the same popup ?

Comment: Yes Prady open up VF page2 in a popup and i save it page2 is loaded in the same popup

Answer (score 1):

In your saveAccount method.

```
 // save the new account record
  public PageReference saveAccount() {
    insert account;
    // reset the account
    account = new Account();
    return null;

    //Remove the below code
    //PageReference newocp = new PageReference('/apex/CustomLookupController');
     //       newocp.setRedirect(true);
      //      return newocp;
  }
```

This will not redirect your popup window to page1.
From what i see the code that jeff has written, you can add an account and then search for the added record and select it to get values in your lookup field.

If you really want just to set the focus back to search tab after you saved the record, then you can take a look at this thread.
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Dynamically-Set-Active-Tab-in-apex-tabPanel/td-p/89159

Comment: Hi Prady just command return null, its working fine but i have more issues,when i click save button Account name  must be populated in the VF page 1 textbox  . public PageReference saveAccount() {
    insert account;
    // reset the account
    account = new Account();
    //return null;
   PageReference newocp = new PageReference('/apex/CustomLookupController');
         newocp.setRedirect(true);
         return newocp;
  }

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues which need resolving in that method. See comments marked PB below:

```
public PageReference saveAccount() {
    //PB: You are inserting the account fine here
    insert account;
    // reset the account
    //PB: And the resetting it to null here is fine as well
    account = new Account();
    //PB: If you call this here it will simply reload your current page
    return null;

    //PB: This is creating a wrong page reference. In your browser when logged in, try 
    //appending /apex/CustomLookupController to your instance (such as na1.salesforce.com)
    //and I expect it will not load - I think you are trying to create a pagereference 
    //using the controller name and not the page name.
    PageReference newocp = new PageReference('/apex/CustomLookupController');
    newocp.setRedirect(true);
    return newocp;
}
```

If you want to simply insert the new account and refresh the page (which will be the creation page) then return null. If you want to redirect elsewhere then create the page reference to the page and go there. Although I think for this use case it is definitely the former and not the latter.

Comment: thanks for reply Pbattisson am using page name only,class1 name and page1 name is same